# I want to read output of unix output into a file

Tags: unix, output

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

channel.setXForwarding(true);
channel.connect();

InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

byte[] tmp = new byte[7196274];

while (true) {
    while (in.available() > 0) {
        System.out.println("in try");
        int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 7196274);
        System.out.println("in try i val" + i);
        if (i < 0)
            break;
        String strResult = new String(tmp, 0, i);

        System.out.println(strResult);

    }
    if (channel.isClosed()) {
        in.close();

        break;
    }
```

This code is giving proper output for small files only. I want to read the output into file directly without using bytes?

Comment: Is this Java? What does this have to do with UNIX?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pipe the results. Eg:
 ps -ef > filename

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can read the generated file using any programming language!?

Comment: yes this code is in java.here i am reading the ouput into bytes.I want to read into a file .